# 1960's film with rock monsters

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've wondered what film this was, which I saw as a kid.  Plot included astronauts landing on a rocky planet,  and if you stepped into the sunlight, you would fry.  Rocks would come alive to attack them.

Comment: NOT this movie, the one he remembers had live actors and was in black and white. I remember the movie but I thought it was an "Outer limits" show. Could never find it though

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96780/movie-about-the-sun-being-too-hot-it-burned-and-kill-very-fast (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 11):

The name of this movie is [Missile to the Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_to_the_Moon) (1958). Rock monsters, a giant spider monster and beautiful girls in an air filled cave, lots of heat from the sun, great big diamonds and a alien, from the moon, who came to earth, but does not make it back to the moon.

This is the movie you are looking for (saw it as a child in a movie theater). Look for it on Amazon and other websites. A great little "gem" of a movie.

Hope this answers your questions.

Good Luck!!!

PS: I have a copy of this movie

Answer (score 2):

Could it be "The Thunderbirds Are Go"?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_Are_Go

A feature movie based on the "Thunderbirds" by Sylvia and Gerry Anderson.

The main characters were actually marionettes. After the landing craft arrives 
on mars, close investigation reveals the snake-like "rocks" are alive.

Comment: Not the thunderbirds!
I remember this movie....you had to stay in the shade or the sun would burn you up, but in the shade, these rock monsters would get you. I also remember a giant spider in a cave too