# Movie about the sun being too hot it burned and kill very fast

Tags: story-identification

I saw a movie and I even believe it was black and white about people who knew the sun rays were so intense it could kill you, they had to stay on the shadows and avoid the contact.  The scene I have in my mind is a man (bad one) who fell on sand and immediately was consumed by the solar light.

Comment: Can you give any more details? What language was it in? What did the people look like? How long was it? How long _ago_ was it?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a scene from Bradbury's [Frost and Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_%28short_story%29), which was made into a movie called "Quest" in 1984.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Caught_Fire ?

Comment: I saw the movie when I was a kid, back in 1975-76.  It was in English, I had a little black and white TV on my room, so I don't know if the movie itself was b/w.....it was for me, lol!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That could be [Missile to the Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053072/), (1958).  Right near the end the lunar astronauts are trying to evade "rock men" while staying in the shadows.  One astronaut, escaped convict stowaway Gary, refuses to drop the bags of diamonds he has collected.  With the extra weight he is not quick enough to manage.  Here is [the (colorized) scene on Youtube](https://youtu.be/vZbPFsWuCDw?t=4525).

Comment: this is it!!! Oh wow, thank you!!! I knew I was not crazy!!!

Comment: you are awesome!!!

Comment: @Mirna, I'm happy to help out!  Don't forget to click on the check-mark icon to mark my answer as "accepted".