# Movie with Rock Monsters

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was a toddler, I remember a SF movie that I want rewatch but do not remember the title.

It is about a group who travel to another planet that had rock monsters that would hug you and burn you up. It ends with one of the group refuses to relinquish the treasure they found and burns up.

Does anyone know what movie I am talking about?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work (when were you a toddler?) and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: Your question has been marked as a duplicate. This is not a censure, merely a note that we've had a [tag:story-identification] question with this answer before, so policy is to dupe-close them to tie them together. You will still get points for upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Movie about the sun being too hot it burned and kill very fast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96780/movie-about-the-sun-being-too-hot-it-burned-and-kill-very-fast), could this be *[Missile to the Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053072/)*?

> Escaped convicts Gary and Lon are caught hiding in a rocket by scientist Dirk Green, who forces them to pilot the ship to the moon. Dirk, who's secretly a moon being, wants to return to his home satellite. Dirk's partner Steve Dayton and his fiancée June stow away on the ship by accident. Will they all make it back safely?

### Trailer

From one the question linked above:

> Right near the end the lunar astronauts are trying to evade "rock men" while staying in the shadows. One astronaut, escaped convict stowaway Gary, refuses to drop the bags of diamonds he has collected. With the extra weight he is not quick enough to manage.

Comment: Looking at copies online, you can see the scene where he burns up around 1:16:00 into the film.